# Share data with friends on Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I am currently developing an app that needs a server backend to sync data between devices and also friends. So while researching if I should make my own server (which I'd prefer not to) I stumpled upon Firebase.

What I haven´t figured out is how public data is. From how I understood it, is that whatever I send up could be seen by every user of my app. I saw that you can define rules like "The user needs to be logged in", but can I specify that a certain child should only be visible to the user who created it? And then, is there a way to invite an other user to collaborate on that child? So that now only the creator and the invited user can see that child?

My app would be running on iOS in the beginning, but I guess thats not relevant to my question, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do that, you can set security rules to allow only the user with a specific UID (firebase user id)  to write or read data like this example...

```
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
  }
}
```

also with custom authentication you can create your custom claims to grant different access levels (for example admin, editor..etc)

example...

```
"frood": {
  // A towel is about the most massively useful thing an interstellar
  // hitchhiker can have
  ".read": "auth.hasEmergencyTowel === true"
}
```

and for the invitation part.. you can also grant permission  by using a child node as a reference like in this example...

```
".read": "data.child(auth.uid).exists()",
```

In the last case.. if the data path requested has a child key that is equal to the uid of the client trying to access it the information will be able to read the data,

all the detailed information is here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-revisiting-advanced-example